# nodejs dns error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, linux, dns

when I use command to test on Linux, errors happened as below, may help me fix it?

sudo node -pe 'require("dns").lookup("http://www.amazon.com",function(){console.dir(arguments)})'

```html
GetAddrInfoReqWrap {
  callback: [Function],
  family: 0,
  hostname: 'http://www.amazon.com',
  oncomplete: [Function: onlookup] }
{ '0': 
   { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://www.amazon.com
    at errnoException (dns.js:55:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:97:26)
     code: 'ENOTFOUND',
     errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
     hostname: 'http://www.amazon.com' } }
```

some system infos:
node -v  v9.2.0

uname -a Linux 10-101-169-37 4.0.0-040000-generic #201504121935 SMP Sun Apr 12 23:36:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Have you tried `https` instead of `http` ? Maybe error raised up because of there is no amazon at http, but they redirect to https.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the protocol. When you want to resolve a dns record there is no need for protocol.

DNS protocol doesn't care if its `http`, `https`, `ftp`,'smtp`, etc... just wants an A Record to resolve.

Don't do `http://www.amazon.com` do `www.amazon.com`

This should work

```
sudo node -pe 'require("dns").lookup("www.amazon.com",function(){console.dir(arguments)})'
```

Comment: Yes its ok, DNS protocol doesn't care if its `http`, `https`, `ftp`,'smtp`, etc just wants the A Record